# discord bot, not finding the correct fields inside html code on a website

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Im trying to have my bot update my discord with new ammo updates with example here:

[image: website example of what im trying to import]

Im having my bot pull from a table on the website example here.

[image: Element from website]

but I cant seem to get my bot to correctly format it. I have my function here. catching the website and using table tr td but does not catch anything from the website.

async function checkWebsite() {
console.log('Checking website for new data...');

```
try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://ammoseek.com/handgun-ammo'); // Replace with the actual URL
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

    const rows = $('table tr td'); // Get all table rows

    rows.each((index, row) => {
    const retailer = $(row).find('#retailerField span').text().trim(); 
    const description = $(row).find('#descriptionField span').text().trim();
    const brand = $(row).find('#mfgField span').text().trim();
    const caliber = $(row).find('#caliberField span').text().trim();
    const price = $(row).find('#priceField span').text().trim();
    const rounds = $(row).find('#roundsField span').text().trim();
    const sh = $(row).find('#shippingField span').text().trim();

    const message = `Retailer: ${retailer}\nDescription: ${description}\nBrand: ${brand}\nCaliber: ${caliber}\nPrice: ${price}\nRounds: ${rounds}\nS/H: ${sh}`;

        if (!messagesHistory.includes(message)) {
            const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
            if (channel && channel.type === 0) { // Use 'text' instead of 0
                console.log('Sending message to channel:', message);
                channel.send(message);
                messagesHistory.push(message);
            } else {
                console.error(`Text channel with ID ${channelID} not found.`);
            }
        }
    });

    if (messagesHistory.length > 5) {
        messagesHistory.shift();
    }

    if (shouldCheckForNew) {
        shouldCheckForNew = false;

        setTimeout(() => {
            shouldCheckForNew = true;
            checkWebsite(); // Continue to check for new data
        }, 300000);

    }

} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

}

This is what my discord bot does as of right now. Am I missing something stupid here?
[image]